# How to: generate .so file using rules_go in bazel on windows

Tags: java, go, bazel, cgo

I've switched (or, am in the process of switching) to using bazel, though I'm doing so on Windows.
I'm interested in calling into my Go code from Java, so I started with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf).

I was able to make that work using the same code as on their Github example and everything works fine.  I tried adapting that to my bazel build.  If I take the `awesome.so` file generated by `go build -o awesome.so -buildmode=c-shared awesome.go` and include it as a resource to my `java_library`, I can make everything work.

Relevant files shown below.

Ideally, however, I'd like to have everything generated through bazel, but despite all my attempts thus far my `go_binary` rule always outputs `awesome.a` (and `awesome.x`).  If I switch to using `//go:awesome` as the resource from `java:client_lib` I am able to successfully see the `awesome.a` output as a resource, which suggests that getting my `go_binary` to output `awesome.so` is the last piece of the puzzle, but the correct combination of flags has thus far eluded me.

Basically I just want to make my `go_binary` rule have the same behavior as running `go build -o awesome.so --buildmode=c-shared awesome.go`.

In theory I'm ok if I need another rule to bridge the gap, but since I'm on windows and bash has been hit or miss thus far, using `genrule` as the intermediate doesn't currently look promising.

Please advise, and thanks!

---

WORKSPACE

```
...

# bazelbuild/rules_go for golang support.
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    sha256 = "b725e6497741d7fc2d55fcc29a276627d10e43fa5d0bb692692890ae30d98d00",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.3/rules_go-v0.24.3.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.3/rules_go-v0.24.3.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:deps.bzl", "go_register_toolchains", "go_rules_dependencies")

go_rules_dependencies()

go_register_toolchains()
...
```

go/awesome.go is copied from the article. 
go/BUILD

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

go_binary(
    name = "awesome",
    srcs = glob(["*.go"]),
    cgo = True,
    copts = [
        "-fPIC",  # I tried adding this after some other reading about .a->.so
    ],
    gc_linkopts = [
        "-shared", # I think this is equivalent to the linkmode=c-shared below, but... <shrug>
    ],
    linkmode = "c-shared",
    static = "off",
)

# This one uses the pre-built awesome.so, and this works.
filegroup(
    name = "prebuilt_awesome_resource",
    srcs = ["awesome.so"],
)
```

java/Client.java is copied from the [github repo linked in the article](https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go-cshared-examples/blob/master/Client.java) (with slight tweaks to the library's location). 
java/BUILD

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

java_import(
    name = "jna",
    jars = ["jna.jar"],
)

java_library(
    name = "client_lib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    resources = [
        #        "//go:awesome",  # I'd rather use this one.
        "//go:prebuilt_awesome_resource",
    ],
    deps = [
        ":jna",
    ],
)

java_binary(
    name = "client",
    main_class = "Client",
    runtime_deps = [
        ":client_lib",
    ],
)
```

and also, since it was important getting go stuff to run:

%programdata%/basel.bazelrc

```
startup --output_user_root="C:/_bazel_out"
build --compiler=mingw-gcc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess I need to go sit in the shame cube for a while.

Of all the options I was looking at for the compiler I missed checking other attributes on `go_binary`.  Specifically, the obvious one, `out`.  The one that actually corresponds to the `-o` flag on `go build`

I added `out = "awesome.so"` to my `go_binary` rule and, sure enough, everything works.

Well that's a few hours wasted.  Thanks Jay for trying to help and sorry for asking a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question exactly, but I can give an example of calling a Go shared library from a C program on macOS. Hopefully that gets you most of the way there.

- For the `go_binary`, you just need `linkmode = "c-shared"`. You'll also need `cgo = True` for each package that either contains cgo code or has exported definitions. You don't need `-shared`, `-fPIC`, or `static = "off"`.
- Exported definitions should be marked with an `//export` comment.
- There's an implicitly declared target with the suffix `.c_hdrs` that builds a header file for the Go library. It's `:go_hello.c_hdrs` in the example below. The actual header file name is `go_hello.h`, matching the target name.
- You need to wrap the generated files with a `cc_import` rule to make it usable as a C/C++ dependency. [#2433](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2433) is an open issue to streamline that process, but it's only recently possible in Bazel.
- Anything that can consume a `cc_library` can consume the `cc_import` target the same way. So you should be able to call Go functions via JNI, though I've never tried that out.

BUILD.bazel

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary")

go_binary(
    name = "go_hello",
    srcs = ["hello.go"],
    cgo = True,
    linkmode = "c-shared",
)

cc_import(
    name = "c_hello",
    hdrs = [":go_hello.c_hdrs"],
    shared_library = ":go_hello",
)

cc_binary(
    name = "use",
    srcs = ["use.c"],
    deps = [":c_hello"],
)
```

hello.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "C"

//export SayHello
func SayHello() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}

func main() {}
```

use.c

```
#include "go_hello.h"

int main() {
  SayHello();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this as a demo so see if I could reproduce it, but I end up with "go/use.c:1:10: fatal error: go_hello.h: No such file or directory"

I tried adding a cc_import rule and including it as a bridge to my java code and it didn't work either.

It looks like, for some reason (because I'm on Windows?  Some missing compiler something?) my go_binary rule is producing .a instead of .so.

Comment: I have another rule that builds JUnit test suites and that actually tries to pull the cc_import into a run_binary rule, and that gives the telling error message:

ERROR: C:/projects/bazel/workspace/go/BUILD:12:1: in shared_library attribute of cc_import rule //go:awesome_shared: '//go:awesome' does not produce any cc_import shared_library files (expected .so, .dylib or .dll)